# Simple, Open source PHP wrapper for Highcharts library

Tags: php, highcharts

I'm a BIG fan of Highcharts Library.

With the presence of Phantomjs, I'm trying to use Highcharts on backend report generation process. (Just to get chart image as jpg/png)

I would like to know if there are any PHP-wrapper for Highchart which it has pre-defined php class so it can be easily converted into json object by json_encode.

(so that it will be stored in .json file and passed onto phantomjs to generate chart image.)

In previous days, I have written one by myself but it was very static and I'm running out of time.. so I would like to know if there are any stable wrapper that I can utilise.

Thanks for reading

-Danny C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please familiar with http://www.highcharts.com/download which contains wrappers for PHP.